# Ionic3 select tab for dynamic/async tabs

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2, ionic-tabs

I am using `angularfire2` in my ionic 3 project to fetch data from firebase database. I am making my tabs using a for loop. Now problem is that it is not selecting the default tab.I need to click myself to view page. Here is my code.

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-content>
   <ion-tabs selectedIndex="2" >
       <ion-tab *ngFor="let tab of category|async" [root]="tabPage" tabTitle="{{tab.name}}"></ion-tab>
   </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

**tabs.ts**

```
categoryRef: AngularFireList<any>;
category: Observable<any>;

@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;
constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.categoryRef = this.db.list('/category');
    this.category = this.categoryRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()}));
    });
    // this.tabRef.select(2) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ion-content>
   <ion-tabs *ngIf="category|async">
       <ion-tab *ngFor="let tab of category|async" [root]="tabPage" tabTitle="{{tab.name}}"></ion-tab>
   </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```